# BlueJ - BlueJ freezes when reading in from a text file

Tags: java, bluej

So for my computer science class we had to create a program that will read in from a text file named "compact.txt" and have the integers inside stored into an int[]. After that we have to print the numbers to the terminal with the 0s contained in the text file and then without the 0s contained in the text file. The code compiles and runs, but when it runs it does not print anything to the terminal and it completely freezes all of BlueJ. After the freeze I can't even copy the code from inside the main and have to force close it from task manager. FileInput is what my class uses to read in files. Here is my code:

```
import chn.util.*;
public class compact
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        FileInput fI = new FileInput("compact.txt");
        int[] ar = new int[100];
        String line = fI.readLine();
        fI.close();
        System.out.println(line);
        int count = 0;
        int x = 0;
        while(x < line.length())
        {
            if(!line.substring(x, x+1).equals(" "))
            {
                if(!line.substring(x + 1, x + 2).equals(" ") && !
(line.length() - 1 == x))
                {
                    ar[count] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(x + 1, x+2));
                }
                else
                {
                    ar[count] = Integer.parseInt(line.substring(x, x+1));
                }
                count++;
            }
            x++;
        }
        System.out.print("Before: " + ar[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < count; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(", " + ar[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.println("After: ");
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            if(ar[i] == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("");
            }
            else
            {
                if(i == count - 1)
                {
                    System.out.print(ar[i]);
                }
                System.out.print(ar[i] + ", ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what is contained inside of the "compact.txt" file:

0  6  13  0  0  75  33  0  0  0  4  29  21  0  86  0  32  66  0  0

Comment: So, I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because when `x` is equal to `line.length() - 1`, `x + 1` or `x + 2` exceeds the length of the `String`.  In fact, a simpler approach might be to use `String#split` or a `Scanner` and read each character from the stream

Answer (score 0):

So, I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because when `x` is equal to `line.length() - 1`, `x + 1` or `x + 2` exceeds the length of the `String`.

This generally means your logic is broken. While you could go back with pen a paper and nut it out, a better approach might be to use:

`java.util.Scanner`...

```
String line = "0 6 13 0 0 75 33 0 0 0 4 29 21 0 86 0 32 66 0 0";
Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);
while (scan.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(scan.nextInt());
}
```

This will allow you to get each individual `int` element from the original `String`

Or `String#split`...

```
String line = "0 6 13 0 0 75 33 0 0 0 4 29 21 0 86 0 32 66 0 0";
String[] parts = line.split(" ");
```

which will give you an array of `String`s split by the space.

From there you can decide how best to approach separating the `0`s (or, simply filter the output using a `if` statement)